# Trapped in an escape room with 2 liars

Tags: logical-deduction, liars, password

You are in a room, with 6 people. 2 of them are liars. The room has a code pad. The people say:

| People | What they say |
| --- | --- |
| Keith | The first and last digit are the same number and are not used anywhere else in the code. The numbers in question are prime numbers. |
| Sabrina | The code does not include any eights or nines. |
| Cassiopeia | The last four numbers follow the fourth row of Pascal's triangle. |
| Andrea | There are no odd numbers in the latter half of the code. |
| Zach | The three digits after the first digit follow the Fibonacci sequence after 1. |
| Bernard | The five digits of the code before the ninth digit each decreases by 1. |

They also say an extra line of dialogue which say:

| People | What they say |
| --- | --- |
| Keith | Don't trust Cassiopeia. |
| Sabrina | You can trust Keith. |
| Cassiopeia | Don't listen to Keith or Sabrina. |
| Andrea | Don't trust Sabrina, and even Bernard. |
| Zach | Don't trust Andrea. |
| Bernard | Trust Zach, but not Andrea. |

**Who is lying, and what is the code?**

Comment: Is the code 10 digit or 9 digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find out who the two liars are:

> From their dialogue, we know that either Keith or Cassiopeia is a liar, and that either Andrea or Bernard is a liar. This means both Sabrina and Zach are trustworthy (since there are only two liars). We then know Cassiopeia and Andrea are liars since Sabrina is trustworthy.

Now we can tally our clues:

Keith:

> Our code is in the form of x...x and x is one of 2, 3, 5, 7.

Sabrina:

> Our code page includes 0 to 7.

Cassiopeia:

> (Liar, so inverted) The last four numbers do *not* follow 1, 4, 6, 4, 1

Andrea:

> (Liar, so inverted) The latter half contains at least one odd digit.

Zach:

> The code is like x123xxx... or x235xxx...

Bernard:

> So we have xxx76543...xxx or something

Deduction:

> Because we don't have 8s or 9s, the Bernard sequence can only range from 76543 to 43210.

> Because the first and the last digits aren't used anywhere else, it can't be 3 (since it always appear in Bernard's sequence.

> Note how Zach and Bernard has a common digit, we know our number is like x2354321xx...

> So the Keith number can only be 7, and our number is 72354321xx..x7

I don't know what next, unfortunately.

Assume all information has been given, then our code is:

> 723543217, otherwise we don't know what would come before the last digit.

Comment: The "who's a liar" answer is even simpler than that.  It logically follows just from the statements of the two liars themselves.